# img onclick need to disable

Tags: javascript, disabled-control

in my page ther's a  label which on it's content i am basing 
a decision such as hide an disable a cupple of controls.

there's a

```
<img src="images/Delete.png" alt="delete" 
   style="height: 18px; width: 24px; cursor:pointer" 
   onclick="deleteRow('<%=row["tId"] %>');" id="imgBut_dltRow" />
```

i would like to undersand how can i disable the click event *or the img/button response
like in :

```
if(document.getElementById("LBL_isManager").value != "")
disable click event / or totaly disable this "imgBut_dltRow"
```

i couldnt disable it from code behind cause it has <% %> c# tags so i could not make it runat="server" too . 
only option is ask for the label value if it's not empty ("") then 
block that event.

thanks a lot !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this - [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/Nk4Y3/)

```
document.getElementById("imgBut_dltRow").addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    if ( document.getElementById("LBL_isManager").value != "" ) {
        e.stopImmediatePropagation();
    }
}, false);
```

Comment: it looks perfectly ok within the demo but in my page it somhow throw "Microsoft JScript runtime error: Unable to get value of the property 'addEventListener': object is null or undefined"

Comment: probably because you run your script before the DOM element is actually created - put your JS at the very bottom of the page or wrap it in a DOM ready listener

Comment: this is my control instead of <input > its 
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="LBLisManager" Text=""></asp:TextBox>

Comment: i think thats the issue ? aspText box should be actualy = input type = textbox... and issue with runat=server could be a problem to implement your code on it?

Comment: <input name="LBLisManager" type="text" id="LBLisManager" style="display:none" /> that is when i put code out of page then page is rendering without the error . this is the view source of how it rendered it